# Variable type not certain according to TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

See the following custom hook. It simply sets a state value to `true` and back to `false` after 2 seconds.

```js
export const useDelay = () => {

    const [loading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const timer = useRef(null);

    const runDelay = () => {
        setIsLoading(true);
        timer.current = setTimeout(() => {
            setIsLoading(false);
        }, 2000);
    }

    return [loading, runDelay];
}
```

However, when importing this hook TypeScript thinks the `loading` value, which is clearly a `boolean` can also be of type `() => void` (The type of runDelay). How is this possible?

```js
const [loading, runDelay] = useDelay();
// const loading: boolean | (() => void)
```

*I know it's best practice to cleanup the timer in useEffect cleanup function, wip hook :)*

Comment: you can add an explicit type for the loading by setting the data type via the useState

```const [loading, setIsLoading] = useState<boolean>(false)```

Comment: You can read more via this link https://linguinecode.com/post/how-to-use-react-usestate-with-typescript

Comment: Typescript doesn't infer arrays as tuple types. You have to declare them.

Comment: `return [loading, runDelay] as const ;` should work

Comment: Thanks everyone, explicitly defining or using `as const` works.